# C++ Wininet FtpGetFile fails

Tags: c++, ftp, wininet

I'm playing around with Wininet and I have managed to make my program upload to my FTP server and change directory.
But the problem is that I want to get file and save it on my computer.
I have done like this:

```
bool Test = FtpGetFile(hFtpSession, "Raven.txt", "C:\\data\\Raven.txt", 0, GENERIC_READ, INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_ASCII, 0);
```

But it always returns FALSE, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` say?

Comment: Are you sure `Raven.txt` exists in the current remote directory? Is your app running with sufficient security rights to access `C:\data\ ` and create files in it? Have you tried downloading the file to a different directory within the app's user profile, such as `%APPDATA%\<subfolder>` or `%TEMP%`?

Comment: @Remy, actually the problem is even simpler than that, but I'm waiting for the questioner to call `GetLastError()` so they can be enlightened.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you I did not know about that! So I got the error code: 12110 ERROR_FTP_TRANSFER_IN_PROGRESS. The only thing other my program is doing is to upload a small .txt file.

Comment: @Raven, on the same session handle? Then you have your answer: these FTP functions are pretty high-level and only support one transfer at a time on a given session handle. Keep in mind you should *always* call `GetLastError()` when an API call fails in order to better pinpoint what exactly is going wrong. I also have a hunch that you will get another error after fixing this one, so apply the same principles when it happens.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Okay thank you. I got it working by closing the session when it was done uploading and reopened the FTP session when I needed the file!